Getting error sfdx-project.json doesn't exist or not readable at sfdx-project.json
I am trying to setup sfp by following the instructions: flxbl Docs
I have set up the sfdx-project.json as mentioned in step C here.
My sfdx-project.json looks like below:
{
  "packageDirectories" : [ 
   {
      "package": "force-app",
      "versionNumber": "1.0.0.NEXT",
      "path": "force-app",
      "default": true
    }, 
   { "path" : "unpackaged" },  // You can repeat the same for additonal directories
   { "path" : "utils" }  // You can repeat the same for additonal directories
  ],
"namespace": "", 
"sfdcLoginUrl" : "https://test.salesforce.com", 
"sourceApiVersion": "61.0"
}

I am trying to run below command as mentioned here:
sfp build -v MySandboxOrg

Getting below error output:
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
sfp  -- ❤️ by flxbl.io ❤️ -Version:38.4.1 -Release:April 24
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Error: sfdx-project.json doesn't exist or not readable at sfdx-project.json

Is anyone aware of this?

Make sure you're in the correct working directory?

It seems I am in correct directory. When I run dir command, I am able to see sfdx-project.json

I saw some problems with the JSON in the VSCode like below:

When I removed the comments from line 9 and 10 like below:
{
  "packageDirectories" : [ 
   {
      "package": "force-app",
      "versionNumber": "1.0.0.NEXT",
      "path": "force-app",
      "default": true
    }, 
   { "path" : "unpackaged" },
   { "path" : "utils" }
  ],
"namespace": "", 
"sfdcLoginUrl" : "https://test.salesforce.com", 
"sourceApiVersion": "61.0"
}

The error is gone now.
